# Why does the right column keeps disappearing everytime I change the theme in prestashop 1.6?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, content-management-system, prestashop, prestashop-1.6

I am currently editing the default bootstrap theme of prestashop 1.6, and I am pretty much a newbie on that CMS; everytime I change the theme to make comparisons, the right column just disappears in the edited theme and the default one.

Comment: You should provide more detail including some code, this description is extremely vague.

Comment: If I were to add some code that would be the whole them code but I think the problem is more from the prestashop Back Office.